# Overlapping Grease pencil showing jagged white or black edges

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, grease-pencil, 2d

Sometimes when I put two grease pencil objects on top of each other at a distance you see a black or white line appear around the edge of the object closest to the camera. From examining it in the viewport it seems as if the grease pencil object has a thickness the edge of which is catching the light from the scene.

Any ideas of how to deal with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Amazing my problem was solved with the 2.81 update. I literally did nothing, just waited for an update. Do you ever get that weird feeling that everything is ok?